# Using vertical scroll with tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, scroll, scrollbar, tabcontrol

I am using Visual basic 2010 for coding. I have develop the code on desktop. Where I have adjusted form as per my desktop screen. I am going to run the application on Laptop. When I run the app the screen is not fitting to Laptop screen. SO I deciede to include vertical scroll. If moved up and down we can see all the parameter.
How can I do it?

I have added image for reference.

[image: Scroll image]

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar(s) should be inside the individual `TabPages`.  You should set the `Anchor` and/or `Dock` properties of the `TabControl` so that it resizes with the form and set the `AutoScroll` property of each `TabPage` to `True` if you want it to display scroll bars if and when any of its child controls are outside its viewable area.